# Expose resource as child of its parent or not?

Tags: rest

Say every `word` belongs to a `dictionary`. What's the preferable URI for a single `word`, either `/word/:word` (with `dictionary_id` a required GET parameter), or `/dictionary/:id/word/:word`?

I'm thinking the first one, just because otherwise there's a possibility that things could get out of control if the child resource in turn has some child resources.

Answer (score 2):

> Say every word belongs to a dictionary. What's the preferable URI for a single word, either /word/:word (with dictionary_id a required GET parameter), or /dictionary/:id/word/:word?

Anything you like.

```
/word/1
/dictionary/2/word/1
/dictionary/2?word/1
/dictionary/2?word=1
/word/1/dictionary/2
/word/1?dictionary/2
/word/1?dictionary=2
/6b1fc184-7053-4c68-aa15-66ddb24d3f93
```

Those are all *fine*; REST doesn't care what spelling you use for your resource identifiers, or what information you encode into them.

Comment: This +1 I would just add that you can also do all options at the same time if that also makes sense. Nothing says a resource cannot have different URLs for different contexts